# Prove or disprove: $f(x) = x^2-2x+1$ is monotonically increasing for real values of $x>1$.

Tags: calculus

> Prove or disprove: $f(x) = x^2-2x+1$ is monotonically increasing for real values of $x>1$.

I kind of understand the premise of this problem, but I'm not sure where to begin. Any suggestions?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Minestrone Yes, yes. I forget. I'll try to remember. :D

Comment: injective $\implies$ monotonic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$f(x) = x^2-2x+1 = (x-1)^2$$

What do you know about squares of positive numbers? Specifically, what happens to the square of a positive number $a$ when you increase $a$?

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you for the helpful hint.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that if we have $x, y > 1$ such that $x > y$, then $f(x) > f(y)$. To do this, I would use the premise that if $x > y$, then there exists a positive number $y_0$ such that $x=y+y_0$.

Using that information, we can find $f(y)=y^2-2y+1$ and $f(x)=f(y+y_0)=(y+y_0)^2-2(y+y_0)+1$. You now have to prove that $f(x) > f(y)$. Again, to do this I would show that there exists some positive number $n$ such that $f(y)+n=f(x)$. In order to do this, try expanding out $f(y+y_0)$ and see if you can find $f(y)$ inside $f(y+y_0)$. Once you've done that, you can get $f(y+y_0)$ into the form of $f(y)+[expression]$ and then prove the theorem by proving that $[expression]$ is positive.

I hope these suggestions help you and good luck!